# Wifi Educational Hacking - Aircrack-ng wpa vs wpa-psk

Tags: encryption, wifi, wpa2, wpa2-psk

I have a question about the max amount of dictionaries need to crack a wpa2 or wpa2-psk password

I am using aircrack-ng on ubuntu

Is there any possible way to calculate the maximum amount of dictionary files need to crack the wpa or wpa-psk password solely based on the information from the encryption?

I recently learned about hash collisions and they can guess the amount of hash collisions that will occur with a hybrid of the birthday algorithm.

Comment: There is no upper limit. If the password is chosen properly, you'll practically never find it (given no implementation or cryptographic flaws). Furthermore, I don't think I've read anything that suggests that any part of WPA2 is vulnerable to a birthday attack or even that the birthday attack is applicable here (it seems to be only used to find collisions in hashes and digital signatures).

Comment: Birthday attack refers to finding the probability of a hash collision occurring. It doesn't have anything to do with wifi-hacking but is serves as an good example for my question.

Answer (score 2):

WPA uses a 256-bit key.  This means that a dictionary containing all possible passwords would have 115,792,089,237,316,195,423,570,985,008,687,907,853,269,984,665,640,564,039,457,584,007,913,129,639,936 entries.

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of a "dictionary" though.